# Should I approve edits that make changes based on user comments?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, edits

This is the type of review I find myself skipping fairly often.

[image]

If you look at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987327/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-unicode-or-ascii/4987414#4987414), the comments clearly suggest that the change should be applied to the answer and I agree with them, but it's unclear whether or not this change actually improves the answer - considering it already has a positive score of 69, and it's fairly minor/deals with semantics of the answer.

Should I approve this edit? What general guidelines should I follow for edits like these?

Comment: This question aside, I've edited questions to include code and information that the OP revealed in comments to make the question more clear.  These types of edits I think are valuable.

Comment: The critical element is Greg's **"matching vocab"** point...

Comment: oh those low reps users which think they know better than high rep users. I usually reject as vandalism.

Comment: in fact the edit minght be little difficult to understand than the original one.

Comment: @UmNyobe I think this is ridiculous. What matters is not who proposed the change but whether the change does actually improve the answer. This is independant of who proposed it! If it should be approved do it, if not don't, simple as that. We are discussing just how to determine that.

Comment: by `string`, I would tend to think that any developer can agree to the definition given in wikipedia `a string is traditionally a sequence of characters`. Hence explicitly stating it is useless and minor at best.

Comment: @UmNyobe They might be invalid or too minor.  Vandalism is when some idiot tries to edit a post to nothing but: LKJFEWRFEWKL:REWF)(*@$#lkSfd; lkf9i432yujl kadsvcsFD:LKDSF)(*$#@FDS dwkf;lawuejf 432l:Dfuwq

Comment: Yikes. This is an interesting glance back into the times when the "Too Minor" close reason existed; apparently most users were of the view that a clarification can be "too minor" to justify a 3-word tweak to an answer while taking no issue with the confusing 8-paragraph discussion of the point in the comments below the answer (that presumably many of the 200k viewers spent minutes of their life wading through). This ordering of priorities was always completely perverse. The main problem here is that the obsolete comment chain on the question wasn't nuked after editing - I'm flagging it now.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If I saw that in the edit review queue, my vote would be "Too Minor". I'm not a Python expert, but saying that a string "is a sequence of Unicode characters" sounds like basically the same thing as saying that the string "is Unicode". It's pretty clear that "Unicode" refers to the character encoding in either case. The second version is probably more precise, but I don't think it's a very significant difference.

Also, if somebody bothers to edit the answer, they could just as well fix the grammar in the second paragraph. That's a consideration I often use when voting "Too Minor". If small improvements are made, but other obvious opportunities to improve the answer are not applied, that's a clear case of "Too Minor" for me.

In general, if you're on the fence about approving an edit, taking comments into account seems completely reasonable to me. Even though, since the edit review queue never grows too large anyway, I think skipping a review if you're not comfortable judging the validity, skipping it is also perfectly fine.

Comment: Now if the edit had said Unicode Graphemes or code-points or code-units ... because then there would be some sense in the change. (BTW: I guess it's codepoints. Am I right?)

Comment: Also there is no concept of primitive character in Python, astring[5] returns a string with that character. IMO the edit reduces the accuracy.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: I think skipping is a nice thing and I would like to do it more often. However, if I feel on the fence I always try to come to a conclusion nowadays, because if I skip, the chances are pretty high that it is simply approved by some robo-reviewer. The critical reviewers are too few, so I think they should decide whenever possible.

Comment: @dirkk: That's very true. I considered mentioning something along those lines, but then decided to keep the answer on topic for the specific question. There's another related problem since the edit queue is processed very quickly: If you take a little time to research if an edit is valid, chances are that the vote will already have been decided by the time you cast your vote.

Answer (score 49):

I wrote the original answer. When I wrote the answer, I specifically tailored the vocabulary of the answer to match that of the question:

> Q: How do I check if a string is Unicode?
>   A: In Python 3, all strings are Unicode.

I usually deliberately do this when writing answers so that the original asker has the greatest chance of understanding the key point of the answer. The recent edit introduces a new concept ("sequences of characters") which detracts from the question about whether they are Unicode or not.

I believe matching vocabulary is an important aspect of writing useful answers. In particular, when the vocabulary of the question is not incorrect, but simply doesn't address deeper details of the subject (how would the OP know about the details anyway, when they're still learning?), then I'm not going to needlessly introduce new concepts in the answer just to be pedantically correct. Inevitably, people come by to try to "correct" the answer, and make the answer more complicated in the process.

I'm not going to roll back the edit in this case, because it's pretty minor and not incorrect. Also, the OP has hopefully long ago received the value from the answer.

Comment: Also shows that reviewing edits one ought to consider the question and not just the actual edit (change). Which is a very important point. Much more so than whether one should allow edits based on comments or not. The goal should be to have a Q&A which is both understood by the original Q Author and the entire community. If the comment should be placed more prominently, allow the edit, if not, don't (yeah sure that's my opinion only :) ).

Comment: It seems relevant that the wording of the question suggested that the asker believed that unicode was an encoding. This makes me support the edit and disagree with your reasoning here; uncritically reusing the asker's terminology meant leaving their fundamental misconception unchallenged, which is unhelpful both to them and to future readers who might be led astray.

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether the comments are correct. If you don't know, skipping is the right thing.

In this particular case, “Unicode string” is a [Python concept](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), so the original text was correct. A Unicode string is a sequence of Unicode characters, so the edit isn't fundamentally incorrect either. It's a bit less idiomatic among Python programmers, but maybe a little clearer to Python newbies.

I would have rejected the edit as too minor. I would find it warranted if the author rolled it back as not being the wording he prefers, but the edit isn't so bad that it warrants a rollback from a third party.

Comment: It seems to me that the point of the answer is that Python 3 doesn't have the distinction between "Unicode strings" and "str strings" (whatever those are).  So it's actually better to be talking about "Unicode strings" than about sequences of "Unicode characters".  That is, it's the type of the string that matters, not the type of the characters that make it up.  So the edit DID in fact mess up the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, an edit should make two guarantees:

1. It should be **unambiguously** better.
   If there's room for debate, it's not your choice. It should be the author's choice.
2. It **should not change** the meaning of the answer, unless it was *accidentally* in error.
   You should never make or accept an edit that changes the meaning of an answer; these debates should be in comments and their own answers.

---

The edit mentioned was not unambiguously better. The wording clarified but did not significantly change the quality of the answer.

<sup>Aside: I'd even argue that the clarification should have said that Python 3's `str` type is a sequence of Unicode *code points*, if being pedantic is the goal. The string does not hold characters, nor do code points even have to map to characters. Further, that's not even true because it's possible to have surrogate escapes.</sup>

Assuming the edit was a technical improvement, it should have been a comment or a clarificational answer instead. The whole point of the voting system is to allow the best answers to have corresponding reputation. By changing an already-voted-on answer, you circumvent this.

<sup>Aside: Clarifying answers should only be posted if they can stand in some sense on their own and do actually answer the question.</sup>